# Replace or change the existing or old component prefix in Angular 8/9?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-components, angular9, angular-library

How can I replace or change the old component prefix in one go?

OR

How can I make prefix dynamic so that whenever want to change it will update all the component prefix?

Comment: You want to rename the component or only want to change the prefix of the component which is by default `app` ?

Comment: I want to change the prefix of the old components.

Comment: If you want to change you old component prefix then you need to do replace all & manually change file name. There is no automated process to do this. For your future components prefix you need to edit angular.json file. I posted an answer for you. it will apply on all of your future components.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Angular prefix form angular.json file.

[image]